# AWS S3 Bucket as Windows Drive

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I wanted to map s3 bucket as windows drive. I am aware then there are tools avalible in the market to do this but i want to solve this using AWS Python BOTO. Also i am aware of moving the files from drive to s3 but i want s3 as windows drive.Please let me know some logical ideas as how to achieve this

Comment: You could try to use aws workdocs. It allows to use the storage as windows drive. Then iti is much easir to sync files between workdocs and s3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Amazon S3 is an object storage service. It is *not* a filesystem or virtual disk.

The commercial utilities (eg CloudBerry Drive) create virtual disks and translate disk access to API calls to Amazon S3. Files are downloaded/uploaded and buffered on the local disk. It is quite a complex process.

You would not be able to create a similar utility using only Python. You would need to create device drivers for Windows.

Generally, it is recommended *not* to mount an Amazon S3 bucket as a drive. While generally okay for an initial load of data, it should not be used in a production situation because performance is not reliable.

The correct way to use Amazon S3 is to make API calls directly to the service.

See: [S3 — Boto 3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html)

Comment: I completely agree, I have an s3 endpoint on AWS VPC so I can transfer data from server internally.   I am running SQL backups every day and wanted to dump directly to S3 rather than moving to disk and then to S3.. not sure if this is possible..

Comment: It's safer to save locally and then copy — less moving parts if things go wrong! Admittedly, it requires the extra step, but you should be able to automate it.